# The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed, PagedList

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

Using ASP.NET MVC and Entity, I keep getting the "The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed.".

Using the UnitOfWork pattern along with a GenericRepository.

The Exception happens in PagedList.PagedListExtensions.ToPagedList.

I tried to use AsNoTracking, without any result.

How to avoid those exception to happens, as it crash the client's interface with an Internal Error.

Comment: You are probably being bitten by delayed execution of the query, but it's hard to confirm without code

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you aren't asking to enumerate the query until after the context is disposed. LINQ to Entities doesn't actually execute queries until you ask to enumerate the query, i.e. see each item in the result set. `ToPagedList` sounds like exactly the sort of thing that requires enumeration.

The fix is to force enumeration of the query sometime before disposing of the context (in the Repository probably), by calling `.ToList()` on it.

Comment: Would not that query every returned elements. Eg, if the query return 50000 results, I would have 50k results in memory?

Comment: If your result set is that big, then call `ToPagedList` in a non-generic repository or similar and return single pages. "I want the nth page of data" is a request that should be being made of your data abstraction layer. One of the (many) reasons I don't like Generic Repository is that it discourages means of data access other than the standard CRUD methods.